# In UNIX Shell Scritpting, what does "eval XYZ='$'${1,,}" do?

Tags: shell, unix

In UNIX Shell Scritpting, what does this do?

```
eval XYZ='$'${1,,}
```

I looked up the parameter substitution page for UNIX which has a lot of options for setting up defaults, patterns etc. But I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: What do you pass to the script? It changes $1 to lowercase, then sets XYZ to the value of a variable with the name of the content of $1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say we pass `Shell` as $1 to the script:

```
./script.sh Shell
```

Then the following would occur

---

```
${1,,}
```

Changes all characters in `$1` to lowercase.

So we now have the string

```
shell
```

---

```
'$'
```

Is a literal dollar

So we now have the string

```
$shell
```

---

```
XYZ=
```

Is an assignment, but in this case is just a string before it is evaluated

So we now have the string

```
XYZ=$shell
```

---

```
eval
```

Evaluates the following expression.

So eval executes the above string as

```
XYZ=$shell
```

---

The whole command sets `XYZ` to equal the value of a variable with the name of lowercase `$1`

Comment: Good detailed answer. For reference, read [3.5.3. Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) on `${parameter,,pattern}`.

Comment: @fedorqui Almost a good detailed answer, just realised it's lower not uppercase!

Comment: @123: Great explanation!

Comment: @123 Thank you very much for the detailed explanation !

Comment: Warning: this is a bashism. It's not in the POSIX standard, and isn't expressed in the same way in other shells (like zsh).